# Recurrence Algorithms

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations, computational-complexity

What is the best method of solving non standard recurrence algorithms?

In particular something like the following:

What would be it's tight bound in Theta notation?

$$
n \in N\\
T(n) = \sqrt{n} \; T(\sqrt{n}) + 100n
$$

My intuition tells me that I have to do some sort of substitution first. Something like:

$$
Let \quad m = \sqrt{n} \\
T(m^2) = m \; T(m) + 100m^2
$$

Which is a bit more tolerable, but still Is this even solvable??

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think the Tight bound would be enough in this case

Comment: I dont think this is a recursive definition, rather a functional equation. Is $m$ integer?

Comment: Yes m and n are Natural numbers.

Answer (score 3):

$$m=\lg n \Rightarrow n=2^m$$

$$\sqrt{n}=\sqrt{2^m}=2^{\frac{m}{2}}$$

$$T(n)=\sqrt{n}T(\sqrt{n})+100n \\ \Rightarrow T(2^m)=2^{\frac{m}{2}}T(2^{\frac{m}{2}})+100 \cdot 2^m \\ \Rightarrow \frac{T(2^m)}{2^m}=\frac{T(2^{\frac{m}{2}})}{2^{\frac{m}{2}}}+100$$

Now setting $$S(m)=\frac{T(2^m)}{2^m}$$ we have the following:

$$S(m)=S\left ( \frac{m}{2} \right )+100$$

Can you solve the last recurrence relation??

Comment: Nice job in reducing it to a simple recurrence. We could directly solve it or use Master's theorem.